# How to connect to Oracle DB via "bequeath" OCI in Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I tried the following url string variations:

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:oci:"+msDbUser+"/"+msPassword+"/@";

String url = "jdbc:oracle:oci:@//<TNS entry>";

String url = "jdbc:oracle:oci:@//<hostname>:<port>:<SID>";
```

Then I connect using:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

But all of them result to a vague SQL Exception "java.sql.SQLException: ??" as shown below.  I tried googling this error but I cannot find any information on it.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ??
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:650)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:338)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(T2CConnection.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:53)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.pca.test.TestConn.main(TestConn.java:75)
```

Note that via regular THIN driver it's connecting fine, so I'm sure my DB is okay.  However, my requirement at work is to use a "bequeath" connection and OCI.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>:<SID>
```

Answer (score 0):

OCI connection is

```
jdbc:oracle:oci:@<host>:<port>/<SID>
```

Comment: Still getting the same "java.sql.SQLException: ??" error for this.

Comment: Please refer to https://community.oracle.com/thread/924664?tstart=0, make sure you use the correct driver version based on your OCI version

Comment: For bequeath, the client and server must be on the same host - just mentioning  that to make it clear. Assuming your java program is on the same server then, create a TNSNAMES.ORA entry specifying the BEQ protocol, then connect using jdbc:oracle:thin:@TNSALIAS.

Comment: @user3487063 I am using ojdbc6.jar.

Comment: @TenG Yes, they are all in the same host.  I already have an entry in TNSNAMES.ORA that looks like this: TESTBQ.PAQ.COM =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS =
          (PROTOCOL = BEQ)
          (PROGRAM = ORACLE)
          (ARGV0 = ORACLEORARED)
          (ARGS = '(DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=BEQ)))')
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SERVICE_NAME = ORARED.PAQ.COM)
    )
  )  If I switch the entry to use regular TCP it works.  So it's reading the TNSNAMES entry fine.  But for some reason BEQ via OCI is not working.

Comment: Is this on UNIX? If so shouldnt the ARGV0 be "oracleSID", i.e. case sensitive? Also, the other difference between your example and mine is I have the "ENVS" setting too ... (ENVS='ORACLE_HOME=/opt/orauat/8.1.7/product,ORACLE_SID=cpsua1').